# Python OOP Class and functions

Tags: python, class, oop, self

I am pretty new to the whole OOP and class prt of python. So I was reaing this book where I got this snippet..

```
class Map(object):
    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

In the last line why did we have to use `return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)` instead of `return next_scene(start_scene)`. Also can anyone explain the code and the output a bit when input is

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
```

Comment: Because if you did *not* use `self` you'd get a name error.

Comment: start_scene is a member of each of your class **instances**. hence `self.start_scene` is defined, but `start_scene` isn't.

Comment: in the last line `start_scene` is not in the scope of that method... in the `__init__` method there is a local var `start_scene` which is passed in as an argument. That is then assigned as an instance attribute `self.start_scene` which is what you need to use in the `opening_scene` method, as the code above does